# Is $e^{im\phi}$ equivalent to $e^{ix}$?

Tags: exponential-function

[In this spherical harmonics paper](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/SphericalHarmonics_12.pdf), there's a periodic function $\Phi(\phi)$ defined as

$$\Phi(\phi)= \bigg\{ \begin{array} \\e^{im\phi} \\e^{-im\phi} \end{array} \space m = 0,1,2,3...$$

Is $e^{im\phi}$ the same thing as the more conventional $e^{ix}$?

Comment: Well it's not quite the same because $\phi \in [0,2 \pi)$ is an azimuthal angle where as $x$ usually denotes the real line. But sure, it's still a complex exponential: $\exp(i m \phi) = \cos(m \phi) + i \sin(m \phi)$.

Comment: Is that $im(\phi)$ as in $i\cdot m\cdot \phi$ or as in "the imaginary part of $\phi$"?

Comment: @5xum Good point. I had read it the imaginary part, but since $m$ is a variable in $\Phi$, then it must be $i \cdot m \cdot \phi$.

Comment: @mavavilj if you look in the document it's not written as the imaginary part as you've written in your post, also in the definition is states that $m$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: $e^{i m \phi}$ is the same thing as $e^{i x}$ when $x = m \phi$. Note that $i m \phi$ stands for the product $i \, m \, \phi$  and not the imaginary part of $\phi$ here.

This should be interpreted as a family of periodic functions
$e^{i m \phi}$ and $e^{-i m \phi}$ indexed by all non-negative integers $m = 0, 1, 2, \dots$.

Comment: 1) this is not an answer 2) how do you know that?

Comment: Ok, now it addresses the actual question as well as a small clarification. From the paper it is quite clear that it is the product that is meant.